# React JS: Creating Cells For A Timetable, where cells on same row can't contain same Team Name

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Currently I have a table with a set number of timeslots (y axis) and pitches (x axis). I also have a collection of match objects, which have the following data structure

```
Object { id: 3, teamA: "pelt", teamB: "Ranelagh" }
```

id is unique for each match, but teams will be assigned to a few different matches.
I also have a collection of timeslots, stored in an array like this:

```
0: "10:00 "
​​
1: "11:10 "
​​
2: "12:20 "
​​
3: "13:30 "
​​
4: "14:40 "
​​
```

The number of timeslots is dynamic and is dependent on data passed in from the database.
I'm wondering how to assign each match a unique timeslot, so a team won't be playing twice at the same time?

My current thinking is to try creating an array like this, where each item would be a column, and then I could just assign that to rows: [timeslot, Match1, Match2,.....], but I have no idea how to make sure no row contains a duplicate Team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea to make arrays in the fashion of `[timeslot, Match1, Match2,...]` is a solid one. For simplicity, you could keep each array to just `[Match1, Match2,...]`, and store *those* arrays in another array, say `table`. It'd then be pretty safe to assume that the matches at `table[i]` correspond to the slot at `timeslots[i]`.

That in mind, you could loop over the size of `timeslots`, adding the match objects in sequence, while skipping over any matches that have a team that are already playing in that slot.

---

[EDIT (by OP)]

Great answer, here's how I implmenented in ReactJS using the component state to get the various arrays.

```
functionAssignTime(){
        let table = [];
        let matches= this.state.matches;
        let timeslots = this.state.timeslots;
        let pitches = this.state.pitches;

        for (let slot =0; slot<timeslots.length; slot++){
            let slotMatches=[];
            let slotTeams= [];
            let skippedMatches =[];
            for (let pitchNo = 0; pitchNo<pitches.length; pitchNo++){
                let match = matches[0];
                while(slotTeams.includes(match.teamA) || slotTeams.includes(match.teamB)){
                    skippedMatches.push(match);
                    let index = matches.indexOf(match);
                    matches.splice(index,1);
                    match=matches[0];
                }
                slotMatches.push(match);
                let index = matches.indexOf(match);
                matches.splice(index,1);
                slotTeams.push(match.teamA, match.teamB);
            }
            let allMatches = skippedMatches.concat(matches);
            matches= allMatches;
            table.push(slotMatches);
        }

    }
```

Not perfect, there's probably a way to do it using for each loops but I'm happy with this implementation

---

[ORIGINAL ANSWER]

It's been a while since I've written Javascript, but check out the following pseudocode:

```
table <- { } //empty table for your arrays

foreach slot in timeslots do
    slot_matches <- { } //empty array for matches in this slot
    slot_teams <- { } //empty array for teams playing in this slot
    skipped_matches <- { } //empty array for matches to temporarily pass over  
    foreach pitch in pitches do
        match <- first_element_in(matches)

        //we need to check whether this match has a team that are already playing in this slot
        while (match[teamA] in slot_teams) or (match[teamB] in slot_teams) do
            //skip this match until the next timeslot
            add_to(skipped_matches, match)
            remove_from(matches, match)
            match <- first_element_in(matches)
        done

        //now that we've checked that, we can safely schedule this match
        add_to(slot_matches, match)
        remove_from(matches, match)

        //keep track of teams playing in this slot
        add_to(slot_teams, match[teamA])
        add_to(slot_teams, match[teamB])
    done

    //add skipped_matches back in at beginning of matches
    matches <- join(skipped_matches, matches)

    //finally, add slot_matches to your table
    add_to(table, slot_matches)
done
```